# My Unity WebGL game freezes on mobile after I take and save an in-game screenshot

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, screenshot, unity-webgl

I have a function in my game that takes a screenshot of the player's score with the ability to then share it to social media or through text message (Like in Wordle). However, shortly after the screenshot is saved, the game freezes. I can't seem to figure out why. Here's the code: (I'm using a plugin called ShareNSaveWebGL)

```
public class RenderTest : MonoBehaviour
{

    Camera snapCam;
    private byte[] file;
    int resWidth = 256;
    int resHeight = 256;
  
    private void Awake()

    { 
        snapCam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        resWidth = snapCam.targetTexture.width;
        resHeight = snapCam.targetTexture.height;
        snapCam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void CallTakeSnapshot()
    {
        snapCam.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        //Debug.Log("Screenshot saved");
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (snapCam.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            Texture2D snapshot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            snapCam.Render();
            RenderTexture.active = snapCam.targetTexture;
            snapshot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
            file = snapshot.EncodeToPNG();
            string filename = SnapshotName();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, file);
            Debug.Log("Snapshot taken!");
            snapCam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

    }
    string SnapshotName()
    {
         return string.Format("{0}/Snapshots/snap {1}x{2}_{3}.png",
       // return string.Format("{0}/Snapshots/snap.png",

       Application.dataPath,
            resWidth,
            resHeight,
            System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-ss"));
    }

    public void share()
    {
        Debug.Log("success");
       ShareNSaveWebGL.Share(shareCallback, file ,"image/png");
    }


    public void shareCallback(status stat)
    {
        Debug.Log("status: " + stat.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide logs, but most likely an error:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/http:/localhost/Snapshots/snap_256x256.png".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options)
```

WebGL builds don't have the same access to the file system as other Unity builds. WebGL build can save files in IndexedDB only or run a file save dialog to save to local machine. You can change function **SnapshotName** using platform #define directives like:

```
string SnapshotName()
{
    return string.Format("{0}/snap {1}x{2}_{3}.png",
#if UNITY_EDITOR || !UNITY_WEBGL
    Application.dataPath + "/Snapshots",
#else
    Application.persistentDataPath,
#endif
    resWidth,
    resHeight,
    System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-ss"));
}
```

[Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) contains the path to IndexedDB root.

Might be even better to share files immediately without saving in file system.